# Questions about using the same DbContext across multiple microservices

Tags: c#, entity-framework, microservices, dbcontext

I have some questions and concerns about how to properly use the same DbContext connected to the same SQL Server DB, across multiple microservices.

#### My Problem

Currently, our software only uses a DbContext in **one** of our several microservices. This microservice, the `Configuration` service, is primarily responsible for the business logic layer; it has many API routes that add, modify, or delete information from our Database. Now, there is a desire from stakeholders/upper management to persist some new information to our DB. However, this information is managed in a separate microservice, which I will refer to as the `Metrics` microservice. Moving the management of metrics to a different microservice is out of scope for us, so we need to persist to the DB from the Metrics microservice.

#### Instantiating the DbContext

In our Configuration service, we use dependency injection to instantiate the `DbContext` object across all controllers that need to access it for Database updates. First, we register our specific DbContext implementation, `DbModelContext`, as a service in the `IServiceCollection` using `.AddDbContext(..)`. The following snippet is a simplified example to provide a better idea.

```
  new ServiceInstanceListener(
      serviceContext => new KestrelCommunicationListener(
          serviceContext,
          // Setting up ServiceInstanceListener
          ...
          ...
             .ConfigureServices(
                  services => services
                  // Add Singletons ...
                  .AddDbContext<DbModelContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_efConnectionString, sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure())))
```

Now, we can inject our `DbModelContext` object in any controller in the Configuration Service.

I would like to be able to follow the same pattern to inject a `DbModelContext` object (pointing to the same SQL Server Database by using the same connection string) inside the controllers of the Metrics Microservice.

#### Questions and Concerns

I am very concerned about reading/writing to the same DB using two separate DBContext objects. To me, it seems like this is prone for issues with trying to read/write/delete records simultaneously, but I haven't been able to find any documentation about this.

If having two separate DbContext instances is an issue, is there a way to share the same instance across multiple microservices? I suppose I could have the Configuration Service call an API Endpoint of the Metrics microservice to send the DbContext to the Metrics microservice, but that doesn't seem ideal either.

I really am just curious if anyone has had a similar problem, and what approach they used to solve it.

Thank you!

Comment: The only real way to `share the same instance across multiple microservices` would be to create a third service, and everyone would use the third service for interacting with the database.

Comment: `I am very concerned about reading/writing to the same DB using two separate DBContext objects. To me, it seems like this is prone for issues with trying to read/write/delete records simultaneously, but I haven't been able to find any documentation about this.`  Multiple connections to the same database by multiple clients is utterly standard.  I believe your concerns are completely  unfounded.

Comment: @KirkWoll even when potentially updating the same tables and columns from both clients?

Comment: @LoganCodes, yes, of course.  Every database used by any website encounters this _all the time_.   As for concurrency, [lots of literature exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control) on that topic, but ultimately it's up to you to figure out how you want to handle potential conflicts.